# ¿Cómo hacer para vincular una css con un html en eclipse y que al ejecutar el html se vea con estilos?

Tags: java, html, css, eclipse

Estoy trabajando una interfaz gráfica en Eclipse con `html` y `css`, ambos los tengo en una carpeta que se llama Interfaz que se encuentra dentro de la carpeta `WebContent`, sin embargo cuando ejecuto el `html` desde el servidor (también en el navegador) no aplica los estilos, ¿saben por qué es?

[image: Así estan mis archivos en la carpeta]

Y ésta es la ruta de cómo lo coloqué en el `html`

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="../Interfaz/estilosForm.css" media=all/>
```

Comment: Ya abriste tu jar para asegurarte en que carpeta está tu css en caso de haberse copiado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

por fin lo resolví, quedó como (antes de eso hice copy del archivo al workspace):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
 href="/ArezuEdicionesFront/Interfaz/estilosForm.css" type="text/css"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

Ya que están en el mismo directorio por qué no lo intentas de esta forma?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="estilosForm.css"/>
```

Comment: Gracias Paolo, ya lo hice de esa forma y tampoco los jala :(